# No scroll on hero until content is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having difficulty creating this effect where the content in the hero is completely scrolled through (100% of the viewport) then the other sections of the page will show. I set it so the background is fixed. The stage div (which should be vertically centered) should come as you are scrolling with bottom padding separating and the second section should not show until fully scrolled. Not entirely sure what I am doing wrong. Code and codepen is below

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xRPeJj

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  
 $('#stage_1').css({"height": windowHeight + 'px'});
  
  $('#stage_1').bind('scroll', function() {
  if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()>=$(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
   $('.second-section').css("background-attachment", "scroll");
  }
 });
  
});
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;  
}
.container {
  padding: 0 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
}
.hero {
 background-size: 100%;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
  color: #fff;
   background-image: url("http://www.jshiebert.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/photo-1424020128429-a60765861de1.jpg");
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#stage_1 {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="stage_1">
      <div class="hero__text">
          <h1>lorem to<span>the Rocks</span></h1>
          <h2>Enter for your chance to explore the Rocky Mountains at River Stone Resort & lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam repudiandae nesciunt iusto eveniet!  </h2>
          </div>    
  </div>
    <div id="stage_2">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab fuga fugit, repellendus, reprehenderit itaque cum suscipit. Error magni, ipsum eligendi suscipit, rerum vero doloremque culpa, deleniti quae id repellat veniam?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus recusandae vel sed at repudiandae ipsam, natus laborum. Sit vitae eos labore, explicabo, blanditiis debitis aut dolor, nesciunt nam ratione temporibus.
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio ab, neque autem sequi maxime architecto praesentium aspernatur veritatis corporis voluptas vitae, nemo at mollitia aperiam! Reprehenderit facere esse officiis voluptas. Lorem ipsum dolor
  sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque molestias hic nihil provident repellat, ad quas doloremque placeat consequuntur voluptatem, repellendus suscipit voluptate aspernatur ea! Voluptatem, est ducimus? Aliquam, voluptates. lorem Lorem ipsum dolor
  sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti consequatur modi excepturi fuga corrupti, tempora, odit accusamus vitae ex, reiciendis maxime porro ipsa quisquam repudiandae, veritatis asperiores fugit. Eveniet, ipsam!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipisicing elit. Dolore fuga, dignissimos aperiam velit officiis cum voluptate deleniti praesentium at et aliquam natus, consequuntur dolorem repellendus eos mollitia libero esse omnis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto
  maxime, delectus, quis eaque ex quibusdam impedit voluptate, in totam corporis repellat ipsa molestias minima vitae laborum explicabo possimus tempore dolore! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa, facere iusto? Suscipit quisquam
  excepturi facilis vel reprehenderit inventore perspiciatis autem dolore minima cumque. Dolores suscipit rem, accusantium perferendis vel deserunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora deserunt esse ab molestiae debitis aliquid
  sunt assumenda laborum, laudantium, iste explicabo quae magni vel ipsum quas quos impedit sequi dicta!
</div>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:css] and [tag:css3]?

Comment: I put it in Javascript as well

Comment: [tag:html] maybe?

Comment: I submitted an edit that changes your code to Stack Snippet format.